# PHP: Regular expression for finding a class inside html element

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a html ul menu which has a submenu. I would like to add a "first-item" class to the first item of submenu with PHP.

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-68"><a href="...">ITEM1</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"><a href="...">ITEM2</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-70" class="first-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a href="...">SUB-ITEM-1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71"><a href="...">SUB-ITEM2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73"><a href="...">ITEM3</a></li>
</ul>
```

(look for "first-item" inside the text)

So far I came to something like:

```
$output = preg_replace('/(sub-menu.*class.*)menu-item/smi', '$1 first-item menu-item', $output, 1);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with PHP? PHP builds HTML. This sort of thing is normally done with JavaScript.

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ?? check second example - How to modify HTML Dom element - OR - Just use javascript?

Comment: @JezenThomas: The HTML is not necessarily output, and even if it is, accessibility remains a valid issue. Joudicek: Use an HTML parser and serializer, e.g. `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be far better off using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).  They provide methods for navigating a DOM.  You'd use something like the below to find the submenu (though I've not tested it, so the xpath might not be entirely correct).  Once you've found the DOM element you're interested in, you'd modify its class attribute.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument ();
$dom -> loadHTML ($htmlString);
$path = new DOMXpath ($dom);

$firstItem = $path -> query ('//ul[@id="main-menu"]//ul[@class="sub-menu"]/li[1]');
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, the second `<li>` is missing its closing `</li>`. Fixing that will allow you to use this, which uses DOMDocument / DOMXPath to change the class on the first `<li>` in the submenu:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc);
$first_node = $xpath->query( '//ul[@id="menu-main"]/ul[@class="sub-menu"]/li')->item(0);

$new_class = $doc->createAttribute( "class");
$new_class->appendChild( $doc->createTextNode( "first-item "));
$new_class->appendChild( $doc->createTextNode( $first_node->getAttributeNode("class")->value));

$first_node->setAttributeNode( $new_class);
```

This causes the first `<li>` in the submenu to [look like](http://viper-7.com/6rgZZI):

```
string(198) "<li id="menu-item-70" class="first-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a href="...">SUB-ITEM-1</a></li>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery or JavaScript for this.

Here is a way to do it with jQuery:

```
$('.sub-menu').find('li:first-child').addClass('first-item');
```